# Do not filter outlinks in Nutch?

Tags: nutch

I'm currently trying to perform a deep crawl within a small list of sites. To accomplish this, I updated `conf/domain-urlfilter.txt` with the domains of the sites I wish to scrape, which worked nicely. However, I found that not only were the links crawled at every step filtered, but the outlinks captured from each page crawled were filtered as well.

Is there a way to avoid filtering captured outlinks while still filtering crawled URLs?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Absolutely. I'm trying to crawl a small list of sites deeply -- say a.com, b.com, and c.com -- and then look at the list of outlinks from those sites after the crawl is done. The Right Way to crawl within a small list of sites seems to be to put those hostnames in `conf/domain-urlfilter.txt`, inject the homepages, and crawl for many hops. However, when I do that, the outlinks stored for each page are filtered, so the only outlinks I get are outlinks to those sites. (So, a link to d.com would get filtered out.) I want to crawl using the filter, but store all outlinks. (Did that make sense?)

Comment: I've currently got this working, but it required a small code change. I'd love to find a way to do this that didn't require a patch!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of a way to achieve this without modifying the source. Filtering a url (via domain|regex-urlfilter) will stop it from being written to the linkdb.

Comment: OK. That's what I found, too. I'll try to get on the nutch mailing lists and see if the team would accept a patch to add an option making this possible. Thank you for your responses!